# Bad performance when using templates and new allocation

Tags: c++, templates, new-operator, allocation

there is some really strange behavior when using the `new` keyword to allocate memory in the constructor of a templated class:

The program executes very slowly when compared to the untemplated code.

To demonstrate this I made a minimally bug replicating example program:

```
using namespace std;

template<class tempT>
struct templatedClass{

    double* y;

    templatedClass() {
        y=new double[(int)1E6];
    }

    ~templatedClass() {
        delete y;
    }
};

class dummy {};

struct nontemplatedClass{

    double* y;

    nontemplatedClass() {
        y=new double[(int)1E6];
    }

    ~nontemplatedClass() {
        delete y;
    }
};

int main() {
    for(int c=0;c<4000;c++) {
        templatedClass<dummy>* A=new templatedClass<dummy>();
        //nontemplatedClass* A=new nontemplatedClass();
        delete A;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Compile this using g++. The version of my compiler is g++ (Debian 4.7.2-4) 4.7.2

As I understand it templates shouldn't have any mayor influence on the performance of the program execution i.e. at runtime the code of a templated class shouldn't even be different from the specialized class that is not using a template.

Also very interesting to note is that when using `malloc` instead of `new` there is no performance difference and everything works nicely.

So after all this seems like a bug in g++ to me.

p.s. I found this behaviour in a much more complicated code while using valgrind. One cheer for valgrind!

Comment: Use `delete[]` for things created with `new[]`!

Comment: 1) Do what @Zeta suggested, otherwise your code has undefined behavior; 2) Are you using appropriate optimization level? I would suggest compiling with the -O3 flag for making benchmarks

Comment: @Zeta: use `std::vector<double>`

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Use `std::array<double, N>` ;).

Comment: @Zeta: for one million `double` aka ~8MB ? I would advise against stack-allocation, you'll crash most programs. The strict equivalent would be `std::dynarray<double>` (upcoming C++14, if the proposal pass), but `std::vector<double>` is good enough most of the times.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Could you share the paper on `dynarray`? And is C++14 already a thing? Damn, the MinGW 4.7 win32 build doesn't even ship all C++11 things. And yes, `N` >> 1000 is really too large, `std::vector` it is.

Comment: @Zeta: I invite you to read [A look at C++14: Papers Part I](http://www.meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/a-look-at-cpp14-papers-part-1.html), you will find, notably, [n3532: Dynamic Arrays](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3532.html).

Comment: While I completely agree that `delete[]` is correct for this code, `delete` was also incorrectly invoked in the claimed much-faster non-template code. Comments/Answers concerning using template containers or smart pointers, while correct code-etiquette for C++, contribute little to answer the OP's *question*. I can see the real "difference" in the provided code being a compiler that is optimizing the entire branch out in one version, while being unable to do so in the other (for whatever reason). I'm genuinely curious what happens when the OP does, in fact, use the proper delete semantics.

Comment: Ok, so now I recompiled the program using `delete[]` for both the templated and nontemplated class. I used the -O3 optimization of g++. But still the behavior persists.

Comment: @pommeshans I don't have that rig available, alas I only have g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5 at my disposal on one of my test rigs, and for what its worth, they produce *identical* code (and have the same runtime as a consequence). I volley conjecture that whatever you're experiencing it is 4.7-related.

Comment: One thing I should mention is, that the real code runs in a performance critical section of a bigger program. So I need to choose carefully among `new[]`, `malloc`, `vector`, smart pointers. 
If I used `vector::push_back` that would probably hurt a lot. 
Like I already mentioned `malloc` also works nicely. 
In the end it is still not clear to me why the compiler produces this bad code only when using templates.
Is `malloc` also using the stack?

Comment: @pommeshans: no `malloc` is not using the stack, and `new` or `new[]` are probably just thin wrappers over `malloc` (might even be completely inlined in Release mode). However your benchmark is flawed because you are not doing anything, and compilers have dedicated optimization to avoid allocating/deallocating memory => yes, a compiler may optimize `a = malloc(1000); free(a);` into nothingness... so, because of your flawed benchmark, you might find yourself in a situation in which the compiler might optimize away the compilation in one function and not the other...

Comment: @pommeshans: ... however the real solution would be to avoid allocating memory in the loop. If you need a buffer of 1e6 items in your loop, allocate it outside and use it in the loop. Also... `templatedClass<dummy>* A=new templatedClass<dummy>();` => **don't**. `templatedClass<dummy> A;` avoids one useless heap allocation and you cannot leak it accidentally.

Comment: @pommeshans just for giggles, stick a `volatile` in front of both pointers in your testbed and see if the same timings are presented. I.e. `volatile templatedClass<dummy>* A = ...` etc. Just curious.

Comment: The Problem is that the classes are in an external library. Although I do have the code of the library I would definitely refrain from moving the allocation outside the loop because that would mean a complete restructuring breaking the modularization of the whole program. 
What I did now is I changed the external library to use `malloc` instead of new[]. This works fine but it still puzzles me that the other approach does not work efficiently. It is a dangerous pitfall and if someone doesn't have the time to profile his program then it will stay in the code unnoticed.

Comment: As for the prior comment of Matthieu M. I can say that it is not an optimization issue. In the real program the memory is used in between allocation and deallocation and there I can speed things up from 10s execution time to <<1s execution time.

Comment: I tried the use of `volatile` in the declaration of both `*A` but again this does not make a difference i.e. the templated code is slow. 
The prior comment of WhozCraig suggests that this might actually be a problem of the very compiler version I am using. Can anybody else reproduce the behavior I am seeing or is it really just me? In that case an update of my g++ may be in order.

Answer (score 0):

As `Zeta` remarked, one possible issue is that you are using `new` then `delete`. This means that, potentially, you have a memory leak.

You will find the (legitimate) recommendation to use `delete` for memory allocated with `new` and `delete[]` for memory allocated with `new[]`... but the truth of the matter is that you should not call `delete` or `delete[]` yourself and instead rely on smart pointers or containers to handle the memory deallocation.

In your case, you should be using `std::vector<double>` instead of `double*` for example.

Then, as Andy said, benchmark optimized builds; otherwise it's meaningless.

Comment: Are smart pointers recommendable in a performance critical section of code?

Comment: @pommeshans given the code you've presented, I see absolutely no reason *not* to use something like `std::unique_ptr<double> y` in your class.

Comment: @pommeshans: actually yes, it can. The type is a bit different though: `std::unique_ptr<double[]>` (which ensures it uses the proper `delete[]` call).

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Took me a while to study the docs but I tested it now. Unfortunately the error persists even WITH `std::unique_ptr` . In the upper example I replaced the declaration of `y` with `unique_ptr<double[]> y;` In the constructor I initialized `y` via `templatedClass():y(new double[(int)1E6]) {}` and I removed the destructor. Still the untemplated version is >1000 times faster than the untemplated one.